# How to port ZBar to NaCl

Tags: linux, google-nativeclient, zbar

Does anyone know any way how to port ZBar to NaCl? I'm making a pnacl project and need to read a QR code from a image.
I'm working on linux.
thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The naclports project has many ports of libraries to Native Client, and some common infrastructure to do so. There isn't a port of zbar yet, but I've filed a bug for it [here](https://code.google.com/p/naclports/issues/detail?id=166).

From the zbar README:

```
...
The scanner/decoder library itself only requires a few standard
library functions which should be avilable almost anywhere.

The zbarcam program uses the video4linux API (v4l1 or v4l2) to access
the video device.  This interface is part of the linux kernel, a 2.6
kernel is recommended for full support.  More information is available
at
    http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/
...
```

It sounds like it shouldn't be too difficult to get the scanner/decoder part ported. If you're interested in helping with the port, it's best to continue this conversation on the bug I linked above.